# Как правильно вставить переменую php в css код?

Tags: php, css, css3

Я вставляю через `echo` все работает, но я не уверен, что это правильный способ.

Подскажите как правильно сделать ?

```
 #footer{
    background-color:#<?php echo $footer; ?>;
    height:70px;
    margin-top:10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать тремя способами, в первых двух это вставить в css код, но он должен быть на той же странице что и переменные и блоки html и третий способ это вставить в div блок. На мой взгляд самый лучший вариант третий, но в этих трех вариантах, есть один нюанс переменные должны всегда быть выше css кода, иначе работать не будет.

```
<?php 
    $blok_1 = "00A1F7"; 
    $blok_2 = "00BC1D"; 
    $blok_3 = "FF4D12"; 
?>
```

Код css:

```
<style>
#blok_1{
    background-color:#<?php echo $blok_1; ?>;
    height:120px; 
    width:300px; 
  }
#blok_2{
    background-color:#<?=$blok_2;?>;
    height:120px; 
    width:300px; 
  }

#blok_3{
    height:120px; 
    width:300px; 
  }
</style>
```

Html:

```
<div id="blok_1"></div>
<br>
<div id="blok_2"></div>
<br>
<div id="blok_3" style="background-color:#<?php echo $blok_3; ?>;"></div>
```

Comment: Использование инлайновых стилей не лучшее решение. По этому лучше рассматривать первые два варианта или вариант подстановки класса.

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум лучше вставлять переменную в html код, а не css:

```
// index.php
<div class="<?= $color ?>">
```

---

```
// style.css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```